# How to stop AngularJS tutorial web server

Tags: node.js, terminal, terminal-services

Following the AngularJS tutorial on docs.angularjs.org I started the simple webserver I started the web server in `web-server.js` just to test it, and to try Node for the first time.
I used it for a bit to view a few files and directories and then I wanted to stop it. And realised I didn't know how.

Please help, just closing the Terminal window (yes, I have a Mac OS X 10.6.8) and stopping all processes manually just doesn't feel right and I think there should be another way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> While <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used to kill a process with the signal `SIGINT`, and can be intercepted by a program so it can clean its self up before exiting, or not exit at all.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/262942/whats-different-between-ctrlz-and-ctrlc-in-unix-command-line